# JavaFX Построение графа сети

Tags: javafx, карты, графы

Суть такая - имеются 2 таблицы: в одной id узла, и его 2 координаты в другой id исходящего узла, уровень сигнала до входящего, id входящего узла.

Как было бы оптимальней сделать вывод графа-карты сети, где изображены точки-узлы с подписями информации о себе и пары ребер между связанными узлами (либо с одним ребром и подписью уровней сигналов прямого и обратного направления?

Comment: А вопрос конкретно в чем? В графическом отображении графа или в способе прохода по данным (порядок выборки)?

Comment: скорее в графическом отображении, сам граф уже таблично задан, причем надо показать именно двунаправленность и вес каждого направления